# iOS Swift Getting directions between two points and drawing to map

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, draw, directions

I want to get the directions between two points and draw them to my MKMapView. This is my implementation:

First, at my controller's viewDidLoad callback, I set map's view delegate to self

```
map.delegate = self
```

Then, I request all routes:

```
func showDirections() {
        let currentPlace: MKPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: location.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)
        let place: MKPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: annotation.coordinate, addressDictionary: nil)



    println(currentPlace.coordinate.latitude)
    println(currentPlace.coordinate.longitude)
    println(place.coordinate.latitude)
    println(place.coordinate.longitude)

    var request: MKDirectionsRequest = MKDirectionsRequest.new()
    request.setSource(MKMapItem(placemark: currentPlace))
    request.setDestination(MKMapItem(placemark: place))
    request.transportType = MKDirectionsTransportType.Any
    request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
    var directions: MKDirections = MKDirections(request: request)
    directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler() {
        (response, error) in
        println(error)
        if(error == nil && response != nil) {
            println("Numero de rutas: " + String(response.routes.count))
            println(response.routes[0].coordinate)
            for(var i = 0;i < response.routes.count; i++) {
                self.map.addOverlays(response.routes[i].overlays, level: MKOverlayLevel.AboveRoads)
                self.map.setNeedsDisplay()
            }
            for r in response.routes { println("route = \(r)") }
        }
    }

}
```

And implement this two callbacks too:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
        println("redenrerForOverlay")
        if(overlay.isKindOfClass(MKPolyline)) {
            var renderer: MKPolylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            renderer.strokeColor = Colors.psnGreen
            renderer.lineWidth = 5
            return renderer
        }
        return nil
    }

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayView! {
        println("ViewForOverlay")
        if (overlay.isKindOfClass(MKPolyline)) {
            var lineView: MKPolylineView = MKPolylineView(overlay: overlay)
            lineView.backgroundColor = Colors.psnGreen

            return lineView;
        }
        return nil;
    }
```

When i run my application, I get two routes to draw, but when I call map.addOverlay, nothing happens. My rendererForOverlay/viewForOverlay are never called. Somenone know how to make it work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finnaly got the solution

For those who are interested, only change the directions callback to this:

```
directions.calculateDirectionsWithCompletionHandler() {
            (response, error) in
            if(error == nil && response != nil) {
                for route in response.routes {
                    var r: MKRoute = route as! MKRoute
                    self.map.addOverlay(r.polyline, level: MKOverlayLevel.AboveRoads)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: var lineView: MKPolylineView = MKPolylineView(overlay: overlay)
Are you sure of this line. Not working in swift 2.0